# neo4j cypher set map not working

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a test query

```
UNWIND [['my@email.com', {auth:true}]] as key_role
WITH key_role
...
SET r += key_role[1]  // r is a relationship
```

and it returns

> "Type mismatch: expected Map, Node or Relationship but was Any"

If I `RETURN key_role[1]` instead, the response contains a row like this:

```
{
    "auth": true
}
```

What did I do wrong?

neo-2.3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have an array of mixed types it is treated as an array of `Any` objects. And Cypher doesn't know how to add an `Any` to the properties of a relationship. If you make the array an array of maps then Cypher will treat each element as a map.

For example, this works:

```
UNWIND [[{email: 'my@email.com'}, {auth:true}]] as key_role
WITH key_role
...
SET r += key_role[1]  // r is a relationship
```

Can you modify your query to work with an array of maps instead of an array of mixed types?

Comment: wow- yes we can! Should be possible to use a map and address it with `map['key']` notation.

Comment: Also currently you cannot store maps in neo4j properties.